# Recovering NTFS / GPT partition after failed "Automatic Repair". Now shows as "RAW" in diskpart

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ntfs

My Wife's Windows 10 laptop seems to have suffered some critical failure on her primary system drive (`c:`).  I didn't loose the whole disk since I'm able to get into WinRE and spawn a WinPE shell from recovery, but her `C` volume shows as raw.

This isn't my laptop, so I don't recall if bitlocker was enabled or not.  I'm thinking not.  But the TPM is working and we have a functioning pin.

I'm curious as to what is the current bootable-usb goto for these failures.  I haven't had to had to work a disk failure since the Win7 days.  Most of the hits I'm finding are 10yrs old, and I know ownership of some of these utilities have cycled.

I'm fine, getting my hands dirty, I just don't know the good from the bad utilities in the Win10 space.